# Hard task - Detect when scrolling from RecyclerViewAdapter no Fragment or activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

Hello I am working on an Android project and i need to detect when scrolling Recycler View, I know you can add OnscrollListener to RecyclerView from Fragment or Activity, but I need to do it from adapter in order to pass data from there to the Fragment, Its something about Realtime Animation, Here is what i have for now in my Adapter

```
holder.linearLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                intent.putExtra("address",shop.getAddress());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(v.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

            }
        });
```

I used the AddonLayoutChangeListener but it doesn`t work as i expect, I cant figure out how to get this, hope some one can help me

Comment: addOnScrollListener is a function.  You can call it from anywhere you have a reference to the recycler view.

Comment: Hi my adapter is another class , how can i implement OnscrollListener from that Adapter Class?

Comment: The same way you do it anywhere else-  you declare a class implements it, and implement all the functions of the interface.

Comment: I used   public Shop getItem(int position) {
        Shop shop = shopsList.get(Integer.valueOf(position));
        return shop;
    } in adapter to get the item from Fragment by position

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding a method in Adapter

```
public Shop getItem(int position) {
        Shop shop = shopsList.get(Integer.valueOf(position));
        return shop;
    }
```

and then from Fragment adding the following

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (recyclerView.getScrollState() == recyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                {
                    int postitionCentereitem = carouselaLyoutManager.getCenterItemPosition();
                    Shop item = (Shop) mAdapter.getItem(postitionCentereitem);
                    int Id = item.getId();
                    String Address = item.getAddress();
                    lblMessage.setText(Address);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
```

Hope this can help someone else.